# Haskell Src Exts Parsing Multiple Statements

Tags: parsing, haskell, ghc, ghci, haskell-src-exts

I would like to parse a list of Haskell statements. For instance, suppose I have the following code:

```
let a = b
    c = e
out <- return 3
```

I'd like a function, for instance `parseStmts`, which can return this in some parsed format.

I've looked into `haskell-src-exts` and saw `parseStmt`. This works for a single statement. It has type `parseStmt :: String -> ParseResult Stmt`, and if you try `parseStmt "let a = 3"`, the result is a successful `ParseOk`. However, if you provide multiple statements, this function complains because there is more than one statement in the string.

How do I parse multiple statements, without wrapping them in a `do` block? Alternatively, how can I find the places in a string which are separations of Haskell statements, so I can separate them and then use `parseStmt` from `haskell-src-exts`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `parseExp`, although the output is a bit large:

```
> :m + Language.Haskell.Exts.Parser
> parseExp "do\n  let a = b\n      c = e\n  out <- return 3\n  return $ a + c + out"
ParseOk (Do [LetStmt (BDecls [PatBind (SrcLoc {srcFilename = "<unknown>.hs", srcLine = 2, srcColumn = 7}) (PVar (Ident "a")) Nothing (UnGuardedRhs (Var (UnQual (Ident "b")))) (BDecls []),PatBind (SrcLoc {srcFilename = "<unknown>.hs", srcLine = 3, srcColumn = 7}) (PVar (Ident "c")) Nothing (UnGuardedRhs (Var (UnQual (Ident "e")))) (BDecls [])]),Generator (SrcLoc {srcFilename = "<unknown>.hs", srcLine = 4, srcColumn = 3}) (PVar (Ident "out")) (App (Var (UnQual (Ident "return"))) (Lit (Int 3))),Qualifier (InfixApp (Var (UnQual (Ident "return"))) (QVarOp (UnQual (Symbol "$"))) (InfixApp (InfixApp (Var (UnQual (Ident "a"))) (QVarOp (UnQual (Symbol "+"))) (Var (UnQual (Ident "c")))) (QVarOp (UnQual (Symbol "+"))) (Var (UnQual (Ident "out")))))])
```

I had to add the `return $ a + c + out` to the end or else it throws an error, since it wouldn't be considered a valid `do` block otherwise.

Comment: I considered this as a solution, but it requires adding a `do`, adding a `return` at the end, and indenting everything for the `do`. It's doable (get it? `do`-able?), but kinda ugly, and was hoping for a nicer solution.

Comment: @AndrewGibiansky You are wanting to parse _correct_ haskell source code, right?  If you don't indent properly and add the return statement, then you can't construct an AST from it.  Are you instead wanting to simply parse the code into a less formal structure than the AST?

Comment: @AndrewGibiansky I'm not too familiar with using this library, but it looks like you could use the `lexTokenStream` function from `Language.Haskell.Exts.Lexer` module, it'll turn the code into tokens, but it still may be unwieldy to work with.  This looks like a job for lenses.

Comment: I think I'm going to go ahead and use this hack. I need this to parse things that I'm feeding to GHCi. Given a block of text, I need to extract the statements, separate them, and then feed each one to GHCi to evaluate it - and to do this I need to be able to separate the statements. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `haskell-src-exts` offers a ready-made function doing what you want, so one way or another you're going to have to write some of your own parsing code. That said, not all is lost. You may have to hack on `haskell-src-exts` itself to expose a few of its internals, but it should not be unduly difficult to throw together -- a few hours of work to get something decent if you're already familiar with whatever parsing technology it uses (alex/happy, I think?), or double it if you have to learn the parsing technology, too.

I'm sure some patches to the package to make this kind of thing easier would be welcomed with open arms, as well.